# How can I work with a string that consist of some special character?

Tags: php, decoding

I have this API I am working on as part of my Pentest assignment, so the API returns a string which consist of some special characters as `\u0026#39;p` and which I need to decode using PHP before saving the return data to a file. I come across some functions online, but they don't decode effectively as expected.

This is the one I have tried:

```
function unescapeCharacter($str)
{
    return preg_replace_callback(
        "/\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i",
        function ($matches) {
            return html_entity_decode('&#x' . $matches[1] . ';', ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8');
        },
        $str
    );
}
```

So from this function I was able to decode some of the characters in the string like `\u0026#39;p` which return `&#39;p`, but how do I decode this further to return the string properly, with its normal character which is a single quote something like `'p`? Any help will be appreciated.